# How to access params in post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Scenario: a user (class: `User`) wants to apply to a course (class: `Course`) online, by creating an application (class `Application`).

They visit an application page, at `/applications/:id` where id is the course id. This is the controller:

```
  def new
    @course = Course.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @application = Application.new
  end

  def create
    @application = Application.new(application_params)

    @course = Course.find_by_id(params[:id])

    @application.course_id = @course.id
    @application.save
  end
```

This line fails

```
@course = Course.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

because in the method that handles the POST request you can't access the parameters, but I require them to set the course_id on the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new_whatever_path link will only pass an id if the resource is nested. So I think you're routes should look something like:

```
resources :course do
    resources :application, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

And then you can do a link_to "Apply:, new_course_application_path(@course), etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your Routes nested and associated, You can use ActiveRecord method since rails can done for less code.

```
def create
   @course = Course.find(params[:id]) #if its nested and associated then (params[:course_id])
   @application = @course.applications.new(application_params)
   @application.save
end
```