# Rails Controller (events to activity)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to understand, what's difference between 1 and 2 line of codes.

Is it same code ? Thank You !

```
Activity : has_many :events
Event    : belongs_to :activity
```

1)

```
@activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])

event = Event.new(event_params)
event.activity_id = @activity
```

---

2) Edited, 'events' supposed tobe pluralized.

```
@activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
event = @activity.events.new(event_params)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When people answer your questions and that solve your problem, you can accept the answer you like most. To know more about how accepting answers work, please see this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350982/how-to-access-params-in-post-request

Comment: I really forget to say its NESTED routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, in general, the two approaches are basically doing the same things and will generate same results.

**In scenario 1**: You are finding an `activity` and initializing an `event`, and then associating the `event` to the `activity`.

**In scenario 2**: You are finding an `activity` and then initializing one of it's associated `event`s using `events` association. Although it should be: `@activity.events.new(event_params)` **NOT** `@activity.event.new(event_params)` [Notice `events` should be plural as you have a `has_many` association]

If you call save in both cases, you will get the same result. Basically, when you will call: `activity.events` you will get the list of events associated with that activity. The above-created event will be in that list in both cases.

However, although both of the scenarios are doing the same thing, the second way is considered to be more ***Railsy*** way of doing things and hence a better practice.

Comment: I missed to pluralize it )) Great explanation, Thank you !,

Answer (score 2):

Two blocks are doing the same. But they are not doing the more preferred way, they are doing differently. See my comment how they are doing differently. I explained line by line.
1)

```
#
# Finding the activity event
@activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])

#
# initialising event object from events parameters 
event = Event.new(event_params)
# assigning activity in event, this will help building the 
# association though its a manual process. Your ORM active record 
# gives the best way to handle that. Your step 2 is 
# something what is preferred.
event.activity_id = @activity
#
# Comment:
# This is not the best practice. Because its not utilising Rails's 
# ORM active record
```

2)

```
# finding the activity
@activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
event = @activity.events.new(event_params)
# Creating event using events association
# I believe your association name is different. it should
# be plural form events.
# it should be: 
event = @activity.events.new(event_params)
#
# Comment: This is the preferred way. 
# Although you can do more refactoring, 
# like moving the @activity on any before action 
# call back to ensure it is not define every time in
# your different different action.
```

Comment: Great explanation, Thank you !

Comment: is this answer is okey or you are you accept something more?

Comment: Of course okey ))) When you said ORM is Active record, I understand difference between Manual vs Automatic.

Comment: okey hope you response with a feedback to my answer by up or down vote  so it will get a value to other people who are also trying to understand the same thing.

Comment: @Rubyrider I think the OP still can't upvote as he has less than 15 points right now. To be able to upvote, one needs at least 15 points I believe. However, here is an upvote from me :)

Comment: I am not looking for upvote spcifically to be frankly I am looking for a right valuation. It could be downvote as well :) because a proper valuation will help other to evaluate.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I agree with you. Sometimes, it's hard for people to do so specially who are new to StackOverflow. However, we all should try to educate and help them to ramp up with process and best practices at StackOverflow. Towards that, look at my comment in the question section. I have pointed OP to a post where how to accept an answer is explained and how it works.

Comment: Both answers helped me alot. Since Im new in stackoverflow, I need more points to upvote the asnwers )))

Answer (score 1):

No they're not the same lines of code.

They tell [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to look up particular files in specific datatables, using the appropriate [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key):

[image]

The `has_many` declaration will perform a query like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `event`.`id` IN ?", [activity.id]
```

It's pinging the *events* data table.

--

The `belongs_to` will pull data out of the parent table using the provided `foreign_key`:

```
"SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE `activity`.`event_id` IN ?", [event.id]
```

It's important to note that you *could* also use this to get a similar result:

```
event_id = "SELECT * FROM `activites` WHERE `activity`.`id` IN ? LIMIT 1", ["1"]

"SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE `activity`.`event_id` IN ?", [event_id]
```

IE you're essentially using data from the same table, whilst `has_many` pulls data from another table.

---

Although these look similar, they are very different in the background. The `has_many` association denotes the *possibility* of extra records in another data table; the `belongs_to` association *has* to have a "parent" object.

Thus, when using `has_many` / `belongs_to`, you have to understand which is the "parent" object. For example:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments #-> doesn't have to be any "comment" objects
end

#app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post # -> only works if there is a "post" object
end
```

Hopefully that explains it a little clearer.

---

Also, you have to remember that Rails is built on top of a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).

This means that each time you use *ActiveRecord* or any of the adjoining functionality, you have to ensure that you understand what this means.

Relational databases work by taking a "foreign key" and applying it to a conjoining database. This allows your [ORM (Object Relational Mapper)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (in our case `ActiveRecord`) to pull the appropriate data from the other tables:

[image]

As such, all the associations you call within your application are basically ways to represent the above relational database setup.